# Copy constructor for more structures in class C++

Tags: c++, constructor

i'm doing program for people register.

I have class CRegister:

```
int personCount
int personSize
Person ** persons
```

Struct Person

```
char * name
char * surname
Places ** oldPlaces // here is former residence of this person
```

and struct oldPlaces

```
char date[11]
char * street
char * city
```

In every class/struct i have constructor which allocated empty memory for instance and metods add which added people or place.

The problem is how can implement copy constructor?

I have this for CRegister

```
CRegister::CRegister(const CRegister& b):personCount(b.personCount), personSize(b.personSize){
 persons = new Person*[b.personSize];
 personCount = 0;
 personSize = b.personSize;
 for (int i = 0; i < personSize; i++){
     persons[i] = new Person();
     persons[i].addPerson(b.persons[i]->id, b.persons[i]->name, b.persons[i]->surname);
 }
```

But i want to copy oldPlaces also...

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector` and `std::string` instead of raw strings and arrays?

Comment: This would be great, but can't use any STL like vector and string... It is homework for school...

Comment: Why is `oldPlaces` a pointer-to-pointer? What dictates the magnitude of that pointer array in the same fashion `personCount` dictates the magnitude of your `Person` pointer array (which is also utter-overkill, but that is another issue).

Comment: @LukasHamrla Doing it without using anything in the STL is beyond what most C++ programmers (including, probably, your teacher) can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a copy constructor for `Person` as well and use it for each person in the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < personSize; i++)
    persons[i] = new Person(*b.persons[i]);
```

And copy the places in it:

```
Person::Person(const Person &b) {
    ...
    // (Note that you will have to do a deep copy for the strings here as well)
    oldPlaces = new Places *[oldPlacesCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < oldPlacesCount; i++)
        oldPlaces[i] = new Places(*b.oldPlaces[i]);
}
```

And then maybe also create a copy constructor for `Places` etc.

EDIT: Yes, and you need to add `oldPlacesCount`.

Comment: This assumes `oldPlacesCount` exists (which in the OPs code it does not)

Comment: It doesn't matter.  This doesn't work.  First, you don't need just a copy construcdtor---you also need an assignment operator and a destructor.  And second, if any of the `new` fail, this will leak memory.  Writing the big three for objects with more than one dynamically allocated resource is a job for an expert.

Comment: @James Kanze - Well, if `new` fails, unless i was trying to allocate several gigabytes, that basically means that nothing is going to work properly anyway, so i wouldn't worry too much about that. "A job for an expert"? Really?

Comment: Btw, here is my template to do the "big three" ensuring consistency without repeating code exatly for cases like this: http://pastebin.com/JVtE9DEZ I think it's actually pretty simple.

Comment: @Detheroc It may mean that nothing is going to work properly, but it's still a case you have to handle.  The code you posted is simply incorrect, and is typical of naive efforts by people who don't know C++.

Comment: @Detheroc I don't see anything in your link relevant to the current problem.  (A large part of the difficulty is that he is trying to manage several dynamically allocated resources in a single class.  Which requires an expert, except that in general, when one is expert enough to do it, one knows that it is better not to do it, and chooses a different solution..

Comment: And i think overloading of = will be very similar to copy constructor?

Comment: @Lukas Hamrla - Yes, read the link i posted and just fill in the `adopt` and `dispose` methods.

Comment: I have run failed :( In every class i have something like this: http://pastebin.com/P6sLzmtE

Answer (score 0):

First, the problem more or less solves itself if you use
`std::string` and `std::vector`.  If you insist on using
pointers, you'll have to do a deep copy yourself (along with
assignment and destructors).  In each object, you'll have to
visit all of the pointers, "cloning" the sub-objects.  *And*
you'll have to handle the case where the allocations fail, which
could leave objects of type `Person` and `Places` in an
inconsistent state.  Getting this right requires a lot of code,
and a high degree of C++ expertise.  You don't want to go that
route.  (Writing a C++ class which has two raw pointers to
dynamically allocated memory can be very complicated.  Using
`shared_ptr` or `scoped_ptr` makes it a lot simpler, but still
not as simple as using `vector` and `string`.)

### EDIT:

Just to make it clear what is involved, here's what's needed for
`Place`, if you don't use the standard library:

```
struct Place
{
    char date[11];
    char* street;
    char* city;

    Place()
        : street( NULL )
        , city( NULL )
    {
        memset( date, '\0', sizeof( date ) );
    }

    Place( Place const& other )
        : street( NULL )
        , city( NULL )
    {
        memcpy( date, other.date, sizeof( date ) )
        try {
            street = new char[ strlen( other.street ) + 1 ];
            strcpy( street, other.street );
            city = new char[ strlen( other.city ) + 1 ];
            strcpy( city, other.city );
        } catch ( ... ) {
            delete [] street;
            delete [] city;
            throw;
        }
    }

    Place& operator=( Place const& other )
    {
        Place tmp( other );
        memcpy( date, other.date, sizeof( date ) );
        std::swap( street, other.street );
        std::swap( city, other.city );
        return *this;
    }

    ~Place()
    {
        delete [] street;
        delete [] city;
    }
};
```

`Person` is even more complicated, because you have to
initialize the entire array `oldPlaces` to `NULL`, then to the
copies in a try block, and delete them if anything goes wrong.

In practice, the first thing anyone with any experience in C++
would do, if for some reason he or she couldn't use the standard
library, would be to implement a (probably simplified) version
of `std::string` and `std::vector`, and use them.  Try blocks
like in the copy constructor above are typically an indication
that the programmer doesn't really understand C++.  All
allocations and frees in code like the above would be wrapped in
a smaller, more primitive classes, each of which managed at most
one dynamically allocated resource.  Thus, even in keeping very
close to what you have written, one would probably develop
a `StringPtr` class, and use that in Person, etc.  Similarly,
one would use an array of `Person` and an array of `Place`,
rather than arrays of pointers.

I don't know to what degree your structures have been imposed by
your teacher, but this is *not* the way one programs in C++.